# Is there any way to create a lollipop chart on the Y axis?

Tags: plotting

is there any way to create a lollipop chart on the Y axis? I see the DiscretePlot function could make a lollipop chart but the chart is on the X axis. I would like to make a lollipop chart similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657949/create-a-lollipop-chart-to-compare-groups

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’d probably build it up from Graphics primitives (Line, Point, ...). Can you provide a dataset to play with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marco! How about "DiscretePlot[PrimePi[k], {k, 1, 10}]"? Is there any way to make this lollipop chart on Y axis?

Comment: At least for your simple example, I'd just swap coordinates: `Show[MapAt[# /. v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumberQ] :> Reverse[v] &, DiscretePlot[PrimePi[k], {k, 1, 10}], 1], AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Thanks ennui! Your solution works! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dp = DiscretePlot[PrimePi[k], {k, 1, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"A", "B"}]
```

[image]

**1.** To make the filling lines go from the vertical axis the the points (without changing the coordinates of points), you can post-process to modify the lines:

```
Show[dp /. Line[a : {__List}, c__] :> {Gray, 
    Line[a /. {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}} :> {{x1, y1}, {0, y1}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**2.** To flip the vertical and horizontal axes, you can use

```
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]] &, dp, {1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameLabel -> {"B", "A"}]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) and add the horizontal lines as [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
lists = {{#, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]} & /@ 
    Sort[RandomSample[Range[15]], 10], {#, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]} & /@
     Sort[RandomSample[Range @ 15], 7]};

bcdata = lists /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
   Labeled[{y, x, 1}, Style[y, 16, Italic, Black], Center]; 

BubbleChart[bcdata, 
 ChartStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0.4, 0.4], RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.75]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, BubbleSizes -> {.06, .06}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "SphereBubble", 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, GridLines -> All, 
 Prolog -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Gray, Line[{{0, #[[1]]}, Reverse@#}] & /@ 
    KeyValueMap[List][GroupBy[Join @@ lists, First -> Last, Max]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! However, I need to switch the Y axis and the A axis so that the Y axis indicates the steps while the X axis indicates the values. I know how to make it in BarChart. "BarOrigin -> Left" works for the purpose but I don't know how to achieve this kind of effect in line plots.

Comment: @Frankie, so the second method gives what you need?

Comment: Thanks kglr. It works! Respect!